# How to handle NA values in integer column when read.csv.ffdf?

Tags: r, csv

I am trying to import 60 huge .csv files into R, each of them has at least 500K rows, total size ~ 3.7gb. My best shot until now is

```
headset = read.csv("file.csv", header = TRUE, nrows = 5000)
headclasses = sapply(headset, class)
temp = list.files(pattern="*.csv")
for (i in 1:length(temp)) bigdata <- assign(temp[i], read.csv.ffdf(file=temp[i],
header=TRUE,VERBOSE=TRUE, first.rows=1000, next.rows=700000, colClasses=headclasses))
```

But there are 2 problems with this:

- It imports all data, but when I head(bigdata) it shows only head of data from last file inputed, eventhough there is nothing wrong with for()...
- In some integer columns in .csv, there is only few NA values, but it wont read it, does somebody know how to solve this? I would know how to replace them if function read it, but... Same case with logical type columns.

None of other functions for import this big data is not working (read.csv, etc.), so I have to do with this one.

Comment: Hum, define "nothing wrong". You're assigning the data to a variable named in `temp` and to `bigdata`. Consequently, only the last run is saved into `bigdata`. You should make it into a list and use `bigdata[[i]] <- read.csv.ffdf()`.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik just one more thing, how to create bigdata object? It should be [ffdf] type? I just need empty vector to input data of 700 000 rows and 30 columns?

Comment: What's the end goal here? I don't use `ffdf` myself, but preallocating a (big) empty vector seems like a waste of good RAM.